# Find undeleted tempfiles in Python

Tags: python

I created a `NamedTemporaryFile` in my python program with the parameter `delete=False` because I wanted to keep it for testing. However in the process of testing and running the program over and over it sometimes did not reach the point where the tempfile was closed and/or its path logged so I could delete it manually.

Is there a way to find out where these files are stored? Will they clog up my hard drive or does python choose a directory which is cleaned by my os? The documentation does not talk about this.

Comment: I'm not certain about this but I suspect that the documentation may not talk about this because it could vary from OS to OS. I can tell you that on macOS any file created with NamedTemporaryFile (with delete=False) **will** be deleted during system restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tempfile.gettempdir()` gives the directory and
`tempfile.gettempprefix()` gives the prefix of the tempfile names to distinguish them from other files in the directory.